# How to put new object in the array in the constructor of class?

Tags: android-studio

```
public Tasks(int linkToDiolog, int reward, Weapon weapon, int q) {
    this.linkToDiolog = linkToDiolog;
    this.reward = reward;
    this.weapon = weapon;
    this.q = q;
}
```

I need to put new object in the array list like this:

```
public Tasks(int linkToDiolog, int reward, Weapon weapon, int q) {
    this.linkToDiolog = linkToDiolog;
    this.reward = reward;
    this.weapon = weapon;
    this.q = q;
    listOfTasks[q] = new Tasks(linkToDiolig, reward, weapon, q);  
}
```

I know that this will lead to an infinite loop, but I hope you know how the code can be lightened and unloaded in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another method in Tasks class to create new Tasks object and call it from activity where you created the class object.